# How to handle ever changing database structure

Tags: mysql, database-design

I am working on my masters thesis. For my implementation I have some MySQL tables.

With every iteration my table structure will differ (adding, removing columns etc). I was wondering what the best way is to handle the ever changing structure, without changing old code too much.

I read that Facebook has a version control system where the can specify exactly what kind of code/feature is available and for what user. As far as I know that must mean that they manage many different database structures at once. How does their old code work along side their new code with respect to their database? Do they do a lot of testing? Did they abandon MySQL all together?

Personally I like [FriendFeeds Solution](http://backchannel.org/blog/friendfeed-schemaless-mysql) a lot. However I am wondering if it is too much for me.

Comment: Facebook use MySQL Extensively. You can "Like" the "MySQLatFacebook" Facebook page if you want to know about updates from them - they do some very interesting stuff.

Comment: adding / removing columns can be avoided by using an EAV - like data model. Adding / removing an attribute will then be reduced to inserting / deleting a row from a table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why anyone would try to use a relational database for non-relational data. 
Forget about FriendFied and take a look at NoSQL solutions. They are schemaless, they support horizontal scalability much better than any RDBS and most of them are free/open source.

- I can recommend [MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/). It's very fast, written in C++, but no ACID complaint.
- Also you could try [RavenDB](http://ravendb.net/). It's not as fast as MongoDB and inserts are very slow compared to Mongo, but it's ACID complaint. Written in .NET.

Comment: I thought about MongoDB especially because I have to store TF-IDF models of documents which are just lists of tuples and are much easier to store in JSON. However, for now I will only get a server with a MySQL-Database and I don't know if learning MongoDB is too much work.I will look into that though.

Comment: Well, actually it's not. The only better point of MySQL for your case is... SQL :-). A richer query langauge. However, if you don't need complex queries, you can very easily migrate to MongoDB. Good luck :)

Comment: I started using MongoDB with MongoEngine and I like it. However, sometime I am not sure if MongoEngine is still a little buggy.